# Having trouble seeing .py work in Apache - it simply downloads

Tags: python-3.x, apache2, failed-installation

I did go over a similar issue in this forum, but that did not solve my problem.

I am mint 17.1, apache2, python3.4.0

I reloaded mint new. Modified apache2.conf file to have:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler mod-python .py
    PythonHandler mod-python.publisher
    PythonDebug On
</Directory>
```

The a.py file I am trying to see at /localhost/a.py is at /var/www/html/a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def index(req):
return "Test successful";
```

While apache is not showing an error and access log shows it a 200, on the client, I get a download this file message.

Comment: you mean python 3.4, not PHP3.4 (which is ancient), right?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I will edit the post to correct it.